# Failed to LoadLibrary from a subfolder on WindowsXP

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

I want to load DLL from sub folder of my application folder. So I put **my.dll** with all dependant dlls to **/myfolder**

I takes me a while to figure out the correct way to load it:

```
m_handle = LoadLibraryEx(".\\myfolder\\my.dll", 0, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
```

It works very well on Windows 7 & and later. However it returns error 998 ERROR_NOACCESS “Invalid access to memory location.” On Windows XP.

However loading this dll from the application folder works very well on all versions of Windows

PS: I tried to use **SetDllDirectory** with absoulte and relative paths to myfolder, but still no success on Windows XP

Comment: Windows XP's support has ended for a long time. Any specific reason for why you need to support it?

Comment: It still has a large user base, more than 40% of my customers

Comment: Using relative paths probably relies on current working directory which is often a source of problems. Possibly combined with XP's LoadLibrary not dealing with relative paths. Have you tried LoadLibrary with the full path instead? Or else use SetDllDirectory with the full path to myfolder, then use LoadLibrary("my.dll").

Comment: Call `LoadLibrary/Ex()` with an absolute path.  Works on all Windows versions. Never rely on relative paths.

Comment: I started my attempts with absolulte paths and it didn't work

Comment: It is a very nasty runtime error, it has nothing to do with LoadLibraryEx().  The DllMain() entrypoint of the DLL crashed with an access violation exception (0xC0000005).  Only a debugger can show you why that happened.  Not exactly a pleasant detail when it only happens on XP, consider using the Remote Debugging feature.

Comment: Nonsense. Using absolute paths works.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has this to say about the `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` flag:

> If this value is used and `lpFileName` specifies a relative path, **the
>   behavior is undefined**.

If you don't need to use the alternative search strategy, you can just pass 0 as the flags parameter. If you really need this flag then you must call [`GetFullPathName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963.aspx) first to get the absolute path.